# Managing huge zip files in dataBricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, file-management

Good day,

I have single 32Gb zip file of variant call data (VCF). VCF is essentially text. The file is ~1.1T unzipped and thus unpacking is not preferable.

I need to handle the data in DataBricks environment due to data security reasons. The data itself is stored in and ADL-drive.

I want to obtains single row of data:

```
spark.read.format("vcf")\
   .option("flattenInfoFields", True)\
   .load(My_huge_file)\
   .filter( (F.col('start')==201127254) & (F.col('end')==201127255) )\
   .write.mode("overwrite").format("vcf").save( My_output_address)
```

This fails

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 22.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 22.0 (TID 286, 10.11.64.37, executor 5): com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLException: Error creating file [output_address]/_started_4696868580366412989
> Operation CREATE failed with HTTP401 : null
> Last encountered exception thrown after 2 tries. [HTTP401(null),HTTP401(null)]

I checked that the point exists in the data:

```
.load(My_huge_file)\
.select('contigName', 'start','end','names','referenceAllele', 'alternateAlleles')
.filter( (F.col('start')==201127254) & (F.col('end')==201127255) )\
.show()
```

Which appears just fine.

Any ideas how to handle this sort of situation?

Maybe I'll try to split the file into multiple for ease of access.

Edit: For those coming after me: The reason was found [in later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69974301/looping-through-files-in-databricks-fails). Essentially DataBricks 'Ad passthrough' credentials are valid for 1 hour only. After an hour access was revoked giving error 401.

Comment: HTTP 401 is permission error, are you sure you have write permission to ADLS?

Comment: @pltc Oh yes. If I take .limit(1).write(....) it works just fine. Edit: without the filter.