# Error in reading files in Azure blob storage from laptop spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage

I have setup spark (`spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2`) in my laptop and trying to read a CSV file from `Azure blob storage` which is failing. Here is what I am doing to get the prompt:

```
./bin/pyspark \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net=<key>\
  --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.2,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.6
```

And then:

`df = spark.read.csv("wasbs://<container>@<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/data/Fraud.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)`

It's throwing the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o38.csv.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.createPermissionJsonSerializer(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:429)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.<clinit>(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:331)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1485)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1410)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:274)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:571)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
  at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
  at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
  at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
  at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
  at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
  at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Tried the following combinations as well:

`spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2` + `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.0,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.3`

`spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop3.2` + `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.2,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.6`

`spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop3.2` + `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.2.0,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.3`

`spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2` + `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:2.7.7,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.6`

but no luck.

I also have the followig two jar files in spark's jar folder:
`jetty-util-11.0.8.jar` and `jetty-util-ajax-11.0.8.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have provided **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role assigned to user.And then Try to re run again.
Df = spark.read.format("csv").load(filePath, inferSchema = True, header = True)

It could be because of **multiple versions of jar** present  in the classpath. And most likely it might have have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it.
Please check if you have a mix of versions of Jetty. You'll need to correct that to same version if present.

**References:**

1. [apache spark - Looping through files in databricks fails - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69974301/looping-through-files-in-databricks-fails)
2. [Read csv from Azure blob Storage and store in a dataframe with
   python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670991/read-csv-from-azure-blob-storage-and-store-in-a-dataframe-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Download these versions of jar:

```
curl -k https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-azure/2.7.7/hadoop-azure-2.7.7.jar -o /jarsPath/hadoop-azure-2.7.7.jar 
curl -k https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/azure-storage/2.0.0/azure-storage-2.0.0.jar -o /jarsPath/azure-storage-2.0.0.jar
```

You can test by doing this:

```
spark-shell --jars jarsPath/azure-storage-2.0.0.jar,jarsPath/hadoop-azure-2.7.7.jar
```

Then do a simple test like this to verify

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net","key")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")


spark.read.csv("wasbs://containerName@AccountName.blob.core.windows.net/filePath").show()
```

It was okay for me.

To be sure you're using the right versions, check the dependencies on the [mvnrepo/hadoop-azure/3.3.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure/3.3.1)